# Jazz: Context root not found

Tags: version-control, rational-team-concert

I'm pretty beginner with the whole RTC concept, so I have started a server:

```
Server clm is started.
The clm server was started.
```

I am trying to login to jazz admin page to configure the setup, the url I'm using is:

```
http://[fully qualified hostname]:9080/jts/setup
http://[fully qualified hostname]:9080/jts/admin
```

I get the "Context root not found" page, not sure where am I going wrong. Then again I found a URL for Liberty admin center page ( not sure why is it used). But I gave it a try

```
http://[fully qualified hostname]:9080/adminCenter
```

I can open the page, but i do not have the login credentials. It is pretty confusing, if anyone can guide me through it'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [this thread](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/216879/how-do-i-find-out-the-context-root-rtc-601):

> The context root being accessed is `/jts`... and `jts` is a default context root for JTS (refer to [Installing the Rational solution for Collaborative Lifecycle Management by using IBM Installation Manager](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSYMRC_6.0.1/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_s_server_installation_im.html)).
>   Unless a different context root was entered during the installation, I would expect `/jts` to be the context root for JTS application.
>
> `%CLM601_DIR%\server\liberty\servers\clm\conf\application.xml` has information about the application being deployed.
>   It should also show application context roots as well.
>
> Can you access `/jts/scr` or any other applications such as `/ccm/scr`, `/qm/scr`, etc?
>   If not, that could be that the applications are not deployed OR they did not start up successfully.
>   You can check logs such as `console.log`, `jts.log`, etc in `%CLM601_DIR%\server\liberty\servers\clm\logs` and see if any errors are there.